# Should I use self.variable for all class methods?

Tags: python, class

I wanted to search whether there's similar question but I don't even know what keywords to search.

I want to make a class something like this (simplified a lot for this post):

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b=None):
        if b is None:
            b = 0
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def do_calc(self, const=None):
        if const is None:
            const = 1
        abc = self.a*self.b*self.const
        self.const = const
        self.abc = abc
        self.result = self.abc**2 + self.b*self.const**2 + 2*self.abc + self.const
```

My question is whether I can shorten the last line in the `do_calc` part to

```py
        self.result = abc**2 + self.b*const**2 + 2*abc + const
```

In my real code, the last line gets too long if I use `self.` in front of all the variables, so I wanted to shorten them without losing readability. Of course the code should work, but I wonder if there's any potential problem by doing this way. I had this feeling that it's better to use `self.` all the time but I find I have no concrete reason for that so far.

Comment: `self` is needed just fo `a`, `b` as you are doing the assignment in `init`. why are you using it in `do_calc` given that scope is local? i believe you need to understand more about instance variables! 
Also, if `**` is going to be used a lot, i would rather make a function `square` to take value and do the job

Comment: @NoobEditor Thanks for the reply! In the later part of the code, ``self.const`` is used again, so I had to do something like ``self.const = const``. What I was wondering is that whether I should always use ``self.const`` instead of ``const`` even in ``do_calc``, and from your answer, I think the answer is "no". Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `do_calc` is unnecessarily *long*, as there is no need for `abc` or `const` to be stored as instance attributes. You can, however, save `self.a` and `self.b` as temporary local variables to shorten the calculation.

```
def do_calc(self, const=1):  # 1 is immutable, so it's safe to use as a default
    a = self.a  # Optional, you can refer directly to self.a below
    b = self.b  # Optional, you can refer directly to self.b below
    abc = a * b * const
    self.result =  abc**2 + b*const**2 + 2*abc + const
```

Another issue is whether `do_calc` should cache this result in the instance itself, or simply *return* the value calculated.

```
def do_calc(self, const=1):
    a = self.a
    b = self.b
    abc = a * b * const
    return abc**2 + b*const**2 + 2*abc + const
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I regret I didn't specify ``self.const`` will be used in the other methods so I needed to save it to self. But anyway I learned I can drop ``self`` at least within ``do_calc``. Also ``a = self.a`` and the choice of ``const=1`` as default look much better. Many thanks to you!

Comment: I would think if `a*b*const` is used else where, there should either be a separate method that sets `self.const`, or it should be a parameter of `__init__`, just like `a` and `b`, since it is not specific to `do_calc`.